# Class method chaining

Tags: php

I have the following code but it does not seem to want to work chained.

```
 $this->view->setData($class_vars);
 $this->view->render('addview');
```

The above works and runs fine but when i try to do the following:

```
 $this->view->setData($class_vars)->render('addview');
```

I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function render() on a non-object in....

But the strange thing is when i call it the other way:

```
 $this->view->render('addview')->setData($class_vars);
```

It runs, but I need the setData to run first as this sets up the var for the actual view, so even though i get the view its got errors where the vars should be? Both methods are public?

Thanks You

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does `setData()` return the view object (i.e. it has `return $this;` line)? If not... well it should if you want it to work this way.

For further reference. This technique is called 'fluent interface' and is described here:
http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html

Comment: Indeed, chaining is not a magic trick, in order to run, your function must return the object on which the function is called. If it's not the case, it's over. In your example, `render()` is returning the view, but not `setData()`

Comment: Just about to post my own answer but you got there first so deserve th e credit thanks: the setData() i added return $this; and all ok.  thanks doh!